# How do I test a relationship in Rails using Factory Girl that doesn't hit the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot

## The Problem

I want to be able to perform the following test, but it fails because I am using build for the event instead of create;

```
event_parent = build(:event_parent)
event = build(:event, event_parent: event_parent)

event_parent.events.size.should == 1
```

I don't really want to use create because a) it is slower and b) the factory to build events has some associations and things I really don't want to have to worry about being in the test database.

## What I have tried

I (wrongly) assumed if I created a method on the event_parent model that returned its events then it might do this at the model layer and not the database layer.

I have also changed the build to a create for the event and this works, but as I say has some undesirable side effects for the rest of my test suite.

## Related Code

EventParent Model

```
class EventParent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end
```

Event Model

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event_parent
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to spec your relationships using ActiveRecord, look at the [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) gem

```
describe Event do
  let(instance) { Event.new }

  it { expect(instance).to belong_to(:event_parent) }
end

describe EventParent do
  let(instance) { EventParent.new }

  it { expect(instance).to have_many(:events) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question.

The reason this was hard is because I am testing `Rails` really, not my app.

I have deleted the test.